# NULL Value on Sending msg from Python to PHP file over URL

Tags: php, python, json, python-requests

I`m trying to send JSON from python file to a PHP file over URL. The PHP file is called and run by properly. But it does not catch the msg data I'm trying to send along it. But it shows NULL.

**myPython.py**

```
import requests, json
url = 'http:/mywebsite.com/api/v1/myPhpFile.php?msg='
payload = {'firstname':'Olivia', 'city':'London', 'country':'UK'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

also tried:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

**myPHP.php**

```
<?php
...

class AddUser extends Abstractor {
    public $log;

    public function __construct() {
        $this -> log = new MyLogPHP('../includes/debug.log.txt');       
    }

    public function processJob($workerMsg) {
        $this -> log -> info($workerMsg, 'W/ADD-USER');
    }
}

$addUser = new AddUser();
$response = $addUser -> processJob($_REQUEST['msg']);
```

In the log, I get NULL value.

I even tried by editing the URL by removing the '?msg='

**myPython.py**

```
import requests, json
url = 'http:/mywebsite.com/api/v1/myPhpFile.php'
payload = {'msg':{'firstname':'Olivia', 'city':'London', 'country':'UK'}}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

or

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You're sending the data in the body of the request, and trying to pick it up in a parameter in the URL. Those are two different things. Look into how to access the request body in PHP, or how to encode parameters into the URL in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alex is right.

You are sending the data in the body and you should request the body in PHP.
the code below will get you started.

**myPython.py**

```
import requests, json
url = 'http:/mywebsite.com/api/v1/myPhpFile.php'
payload = {'firstname':'Olivia', 'city':'London', 'country':'UK'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

**myPHP.php**

```
<?php
...
class AddUser extends Abstractor {
    public $log;

    public function __construct() {
        $this -> log = new MyLogPHP('../includes/debug.log.txt');       
    }

    public function processJob($workerMsg) {
        $this -> log -> info($workerMsg, 'W/ADD-USER');
    }
}

$addUser = new AddUser();
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$response = $addUser -> processJob($entityBody);
```